# Implement header, footer and menubar in Google Web Toolkit (GWT)

Tags: gwt

I just started learning Google Web Toolkit (GWT). How do I implement header, left navigation bar and footer in my GWT application?

How can i place the header and footer in one page and reuse the same in all other pages?

Please help me how can i achieve the above requirement?

Answer (score 2):

I like using [SplitLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SplitLayoutPanel.html). Here you will basically only change the center panel and leave northe west etc alone.
You can find a very good overview [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels).

Comment: ... or use `SplitLayoutPanel`'s superclass, [`DockLayoutPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html), if you don't need user-positioned splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template in Ui:Binder with your basic layout, and use this template for all new pages.

Another option is to create a custom widget for you menu, header and footer. Then you again can use a template for new pages, but instead of including each button, label, etc., you just include your custom headerWidget, footerWidget and menuWidget.

As others already suggested, you use one of the LayoutPanels to organize your page. My favorite is LayoutPanel. You add your headerWidget, footerWidget, and menuWidget to this LayoutPanel and specify their position.

I recommend that you use a Ui:Binder for this: it's a more convenient way to do layouts, it's very visual (helps to cut on the number of mistakes),  and much easier to maintain.